# Visual Studio won't load custom form

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, custom-controls

Right, so I have a custom form I designed for a game I'm making in VB.NET for school. It resides in a namespace 'UI'. It (obviously) inherits from Form. I have another code file in the project namespace called 'Client'. Client inherits from my custom form class. However, two problems arise:

1. If I export the custom form class as template and then add it to the project using Project > Add New Item..., it designs the form as normal, with none of my alterations, and under Properties, claims that it *is* an instance of `Windows.Forms.Form`. It does show the form as normal when run, however all the internal code from my custom form is in Client.vb, which I don't want.
2. If I simply add a code file to the project namespace and add `Inherits Window` to it, it does not generate a designer file and does not actually show the form at all because when I set the `MainForm` to 'Client', it instead shows the class it derives from, in the UI namespace.

I have little experience in custom form building, so any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: How are you exporting the custom form class?  File, Export Template?

Comment: You are pretty lost here.  Creating an item template for a custom form is of very little use, especially when it requires other source code files to be functional.  You can't arbitrarily change the base class and still hope that it works in the designer.  Just don't do these things, they don't work.

Comment: Yes, I'm exporting it through File > Export Template.